# Procesar select si count() es mayor que cero

Tags: php

Si unos registros cumplen la condición quiero mostrarlos en pantalla.
Si ningún registro cumple la condición que muestre un mensaje.
Tengo este código y muestro los datos usando plantilla Smarty.
Pero me arroja un mensaje que la $matriz no está definida. La tabla tiene registros.
El código es este:

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'X'";
if ($sth = $BD->query($sql)) {
    if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        $sql = "SELECT cod, nom FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'X'";
        while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $matriz[] = new DatosVO($fila['cod'], $fila['nom']);
        }
        $NoRegistros = "";
    } else {
        $NoRegistros = "NO EXISTEN REGISTROS";
        $matriz = '';
    }
    $exito = TRUE;
}
$tpl = new Plantilla();
if ($exito) {
    $tpl->assign('NoRegistros', $NoRegistros);
    $tpl->assign('lista', $matriz);
    $tpl->display('mostrar.tpl.php');
} else {
    $tpl->assign('mensaje', $mensaje);
    $tpl->display('fallo.tpl.php');
}
```

Yo utilizaba el rowcount() de esta manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT cod, nom FROM tabla WHERE condicion = 'X'";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

    while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $matriz[] = new DatosVO($fila['cod'], $fila['nom']);
    }
    $NoRegistros = "";

} else {
    $NoRegistros = "NO EXISTEN REGISTROS";
    $prenonomstuds = "";
}
```

Pero en el manual de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php ejemplo #2 dice que rowcount no devuelve los registros de un select y recomienda usar query().

Comment: te marca error cuando existen o cuando no existen registros?

Comment: ¿y si en vez de un `COUNT(*)` haces esta consulta: `SELECT cod, nom FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'X'` y verificas si esa consulta trajo datos?

Comment: Sí hay registros que cumplen la condición.

Comment: donde ejecutas tu segundo $sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya que nunca corres tu segundo Query, no encuentras ['cod'] ni ['nom'] y ya que tu matriz es creada dentro del while esta no se define cuando la llamas en el assign.

si lo defines antes igual siempre te marcaría una tabla vacía.

así que necesitarías hacer un array vació con $matriz=[]; y luego llenarla con tus datos, no tiene caso hacer dos llamadas a tu base de datos solo para conocer la longitud del resultado, solo llama tu segundo Query y si la matriz esta vacía tendrá un tamaño de 0.

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sql = "SELECT cod, nom FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'X'";
$matriz=[];
if ($sth = $BD->query($sql)) {
    while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $matriz[] = new DatosVO($fila['cod'], $fila['nom']);
    }
    if (count($matriz)==0){
        $NoRegistros = "NO EXISTEN REGISTROS";
    }
    $exito = TRUE;
}
$tpl = new Plantilla();
if ($exito) {
    $tpl->assign('NoRegistros', $NoRegistros);
    $tpl->assign('lista', $matriz);
    $tpl->display('mostrar.tpl.php');
} else {
    $tpl->assign('mensaje', $mensaje);
    $tpl->display('fallo.tpl.php');
}
```

Comment: El segundo query. Cierto!. Con respecto a tu código si en caso no hay registros igual va a procesar el while? Pregunto porque es después que preguntas si $matriz tiene o no registros.

Comment: cuando no hay registros el código dentro del while no se ejecuta, por que en esencia le estas diciendo has esto mientras existan registros.

Comment: Una consulta más. El While para efectos de optimización se puede cambiar por un Foreach o no es necesario?

Comment: Puedes cambiarlo no haría ninguna diferencia en la forma que se ejecuta el resto del código.

Comment: El código es redundante. Desde que ejecutas el query : `if ($sth = $BD->query($sql)) {` ya sabes si hay registros, pues en PDO el método `query` devuelve un array vacío si no hay registros. Por tanto todo el bloque `if count($matriz)>0{...` es inútil.

Comment: @A.Cedano, cierto gracias, lo simplifico.

Comment: Hay que agregar los parentesis para que quede así: **if (count($matriz) == 0) { ... }**

Comment: Hola estuve probando el código y el If se ejecuta si el Select tiene o no tiene registros. @JorgeArturoJuarez

Comment: @Piropeator En PDO puedes comprobar si el query tiene registros haciendo simplemente esto: `$datos= $BD->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` haciendo eso, ya tendrás tu conjunto de resultados en la variable `$datos`. Luego para saber si hay algo haces por ejemplo: `if ($datos){...iterar sobre los datos con un bucle }else{... no hay datos }`,  En PDO, haciédolo de esa manera, la variable `$datos` adquirirá el valor devuelto por la consulta, el cual será `NULL` en el caso de registros vacíos o de error en la consulta.

Comment: En la respuesta el primer If solamente valida que exista la variable $sth pues la cantidad de registros se ve dentro en el if (count($matriz)==0). Entonces para qué colocar el primer If?

Comment: @Piropeator El 1er if es el importante, mientras que este sobra: `if (count($matriz)==0){` ya que quitando ese y poniendo el mensaje de "No existe registro" en el `else` de `if ($sth ...)` debería funcionar. Quizá ahora se ejecuta porque aunque no haya valores en el `$sth` la instancia que creas de la clase `DatosVO` agrega algo a la variable `$matriz` Además , esto se ejecuta siempre también `if ($exito) {` porque `$exito` siempre es TRUE en el código.

Comment: Te cuento que he probado esto y en ambos casos me muestra Hay Registros: `$sql = "SELECT cod, nom FROM tabla WHERE condicion";
if ($sth = $BD->query($sql)) {
  echo "HAY REGISTROS";
} else {
  echo "NO HAY REGISTROS";
}` Cuál es mi error?